# Error handling opendir

Tags: php, error-handling, opendir

I always get a warming when I tried to use the opendir() but the folder does not exists. How can I handle this error, and verify if the folder exists before open the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`is_dir($directory)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)

> Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is a directory, FALSE otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the directory exists with `is_dir()`

```
if(is_dir($dir)){
    // code
}
```